# Oracle : auto add the current user id in a new entry

Tags: oracle, userid

I have a table to create and i need to get the current user id. 
I wonder if a solution like for the current date :

```
is_date_enr     date        default sysdate not null,
```

is possible.

Comment: Your posted code is about DATE, there is nothing related to USER/SCHEMA? Please explain your requirement.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally new on oracle base. So, i need to get the user id of the person who makes an entry in my table.

Comment: Use `USER` for username just like you used SYSDATE. For example, `select user from dual;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UID and USER [pseudocolumns](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Pseudo-column#UID_and_USER) to do that:

```
create table test (
  tst_date date default sysdate not null,
  tst_user varchar2(20) default user not null,
  tst_uid number default uid not null,
  field1 number,
  field2 varchar2(10));
```

Test:

```
insert into test (field1, field2) values (1, 'ABC');
insert into test (field1, field2) values (2, 'DEF');
insert into test (field1, field2) values (3, 'XYZ');

select * from test;

TST_DATE             TST_USER  TST_UID FIELD1    FIELD2
-------------------  --------  -------  --------  --------
2015-03-23 17:41:28  SCOTT         236         1  ABC
2015-03-23 17:41:28  SCOTT         236         2  DEF
2015-03-23 17:41:28  SCOTT         236         3  XYZ
```

Columns `TST_DATE`, `TST_USER` and `TST_UID` were filled automatically.